# Which entity to choose as "isPartOf" of WebSite according to Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

If think logically - hierarchy the following:

`WebSite` → `WebPage` → `mainEntity` → `Article`

So, I must state `WebPage` as `isPartOf` `WebSite`.

From the other side I saw many times that for example only `Article` (`mainEntity`) section stated as `isPartOf` `WebSite`.

I understand that main idea of `WebPage` is `mainEntity` (header, footer, navigation are always the same on all WebPage-s), but anyway the question is:

**Should I state `WebPage` as part of `Website` or only `mainEntity` of `WebPage`?** The purpose - better SEO.

Comment: Schema.org markup has little to no effect on search engine rankings.   But even if it did I'm not sure how you would use the answer to this question to improve your website.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Everyone told me following: Microdata->better readability by search engines->better trust-> higher rankings and better snippets. Am i wrong?

Comment: Marking up reviews with microdata may give star snippets in search.  In theory it makes search engines be able to understand your site in some machine readable ways, but it isn't clear which of those they would use.   I haven't seen any evidence for more trust when using them and certainly not higher rankings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these structures make the most sense (from least detailed to most detailed, and most likely also from most popular to least popular):

1. `Article`
2. `WebPage` `mainEntity` `Article`
3. `WebSite` `hasPart` `WebPage` `mainEntity` `Article`

The [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart)/[`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf) properties are rather broadly defined (a work that is "in some sense" part of another work), so one could even argue to use it in addition to `mainEntity` (i.e., `WebPage` `hasPart`/`mainEntity` `Article`), but in my opinion that’s not a perfect match and probably not necessary.

Which to choose? This mostly depends on what data you want to provide. If you don’t have relevant data about your website, there is probably no point in providing a `WebSite` item. If you provide a `WebSite` item (e.g. for Google’s [Sitelinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)), it might make sense to define this item only on the homepage. If you want to state that your `WebPage` items are part of this `WebSite`, you could reference its URI instead of providing a separate `WebSite` item on each of your pages, repeating the same information every time.

Comment: You told "you could reference its URI" - i didn't clearly understand what do you mean? How i can " reference URI"?

Comment: @Evgeny: In Microdata, you could give the `WebSite` item a URI via the `itemid` attribute (`itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" itemid="#site"`), and then reference this URI as value, for example from a `WebPage`: `<link itemprop="isPartOf" href="/#site" />` (a URL value for `isPartOf` is not expected, but allowed).  -- However, consumers (like Google) might not support this very well.